# Modular and time difference between two dates

Tags: python

I am trying to convert from `(day,hour,minut,seconds)` to seconds for 2 dates, make the difference, then reverse. What I have done basically works but for some cases it returns a wrong result.

Entry data form to test:

```
13
6 0 8 22 20 18 10 28
2 5 32 20 7 1 21 51
11 5 54 35 15 15 11 24
6 2 3 49 16 10 49 9
1 1 37 59 14 22 13 0
3 15 15 10 28 18 37 21
21 9 54 11 22 1 11 13
12 3 37 24 20 12 42 50
16 11 25 12 26 1 37 19
7 4 59 31 12 8 54 23
3 10 22 49 24 19 36 32
1 1 21 2 29 10 51 13
5 22 2 37 29 1 53 59
```

It returns a wrong value always in the hours result (it adds 36)

The code:

```
count=lambda a,b,c,d:a+b+c+d

def magic_date_to_numbers(a,b,c,d):
    a*=60**3
    b*=60**2
    c*=60
    return count(a,b,c,d)

def reverse_magic(n):
    a=n/(60**3)
    b=(n%(60**3))/(60**2)
    c=(((n%60**3)%60**2))/60
    d=((n%(60**3))%(60**2))%60

    print "(%s %s %s %s) "%(str(a),str(b),str(c),str(d))

for i in range(0,int(raw_input())):
    d=map(long,raw_input().split(" "))
    n1=magic_date_to_numbers(d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3])
    n2=magic_date_to_numbers(d[4],d[5],d[6],d[7])
    reverse_magic(abs(n2-n1))
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already really good built-ins and utilities for handling these types of issues but I think the mistake that you are making is very simple:  there are 24 hours in a day, not 60 (60 - 24 = 36).

```
from datetime import timedelta

def magic_date_to_numbers(days, hours, minutes, seconds):
    t = timedelta(days=days, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
    return t.total_seconds()
    # hours += days * 24 # 24 hours in a day
    # minutes += hours * 60 # 60 minutes in an hour
    # seconds += minutes * 60 # 60 seconds in a minute
    # return seconds

def reverse_magic(n):
    t = timedelta(seconds=n)
    n = t.seconds
    seconds, minutes = n % 60, n // 60
    minutes, hours = minutes % 60, minutes // 60
    # hours, days = hours % 24, hours // 24    
    print "(%s %s %s %s) " % (t.days, hours, minutes, seconds)

for i in range(0,int(raw_input())):
    d=map(long,raw_input().split(" "))
    n1=magic_date_to_numbers(d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3])
    n2=magic_date_to_numbers(d[4],d[5],d[6],d[7])
    reverse_magic(abs(n2-n1))
```